# Create xls file gibrish

Tags: c#, asp.net, xls

I am trying to return xls file in hebrew but it returns me gibrish letters and writes that the file extension isn't the file real content.

Please help me.

```
public void ExportAddBalanceExcel(int CompanyID)
{
    string writer = "";
    writer += "<table><tr><td>UserName</td><td> PrivateName</td><td>LastName</td><td>Balance</td></tr>";

    List<CompanyEmployee> employees = Company.LoadByID(CompanyID).LoadAllEmployees();

    foreach (BLL.CompanyEmployee e in employees)
    {
        writer += "<tr>";
        writer += "<td>" + e.EmployeeUserName+ "</td>";
        writer += "<td>" + e.EmployeeFirstName+ "</td>";
        writer += "<td>" + e.EmployeeLastName  + "</td>";
        writer += "</tr>";
    }
    writer += "</table>";
    string currentData = DateTime.Now.Day + "_" + DateTime.Now.Month + "_" + DateTime.Now.Year;

    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=AddBalanceToEmployees_" + currentData + ".xls");
    Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1255");
    Response.Write(writer);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();            
}
```

Comment: That isn't XLS.  Also, use UTF8.

Comment: what should i do for xls?

Comment: utf 8 isnt good for hebrew, there is still gibrish

Comment: Then you're using it wrong.  UTF8 supports the full range of Unicode characters.

Comment: You can write XLS or XLSX using OLEDB.

Comment: oh pleas do me a favor i used it very good   Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");

Comment: Do you *have* to create a .XLS file? Or would creating a .XLSX file be acceptable? .XLSX is simple, there's a ton of excellent libraries for creating it.

Answer (score 0):

How would this be opened in Excel?  You seem to be generating some HTML-like syntax that you're telling the client is an Excel file.

To write to Excel, you could use [COM Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173186%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (though [this is not recommended for use server-side](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)), or if XLSX is sufficent you could look at the OpenXML SDK (a simple example [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrisrae/archive/2011/08/18/creating-a-simple-xlsx-from-scratch-using-the-open-xml-sdk.aspx)).  If you require XLS you might want to check out some 3rd party libraries.